# Differential equation: $x' = 1 - x^2$, $x(0) = 3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Title says it all:

$$\begin{cases}
x' = 1 - x^2\\
x(0) = 3
\end{cases}.$$

Had this problem on a quiz today and I was unsure of how to solve it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Separation of Variables.

Comment: Use Amzoti's hint and also $1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x).$

Answer (score 1):

This kind of DE can be solved like this (with a large lack of rigurosity):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x'&=&1-x^2\\
\frac{dx}{dt}&=&1-x^2\\
\frac{dx}{1-x^2}&=&dt\qquad/\int\\
\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}dx&=&\int dt\qquad/\text{parcial fractions}\\
\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{1-x}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{1+x}dx&=&t+C\\
\frac{1}{2}\big(-\ln(1-x)+\ln(1+x)\big)&=&t+C\\
\frac{1}{2}\ln\bigg(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\bigg)&=&t+C\\
\ln\bigg(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\bigg)&=&2t+K\qquad/\exp\\
\frac{1+x}{1-x}&=&\mathrm{e}^{2t+K}\\
1+x&=&(1-x)\mathrm{e}^{2t+K}\\
1-\mathrm{e}^{2t+K}&=&-x(1+\mathrm{e}^{2t+K})\\
\\
\Rightarrow x&=&\frac{\mathrm{e}^{2t+K}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{2t+K}+1}=\frac{K_0\mathrm{e}^{2t}-1}{K_0\mathrm{e}^{2t}+1}
\end{array}$$

Then, using the initial condition $x(0)=3$:
$$x(0)=\frac{K_0\mathrm{e}^{2\cdot0}-1}{K_0\mathrm{e}^{2\cdot0}+1}=\frac{K_0-1}{K_0+1}=3$$
$$\Rightarrow K_0=\frac{1+3}{1-3}=-2$$

Then,
$$x(t)=\frac{-2\mathrm{e}^{2t}-1}{-2\mathrm{e}^{2t}+1}=\frac{2\mathrm{e}^{2t}+1}{2\mathrm{e}^{2t}-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Divide both sides by $1-x^2$, you get:

$$\frac{x'}{1-x^2}=1$$

Now integrate both sides from $t_0$ to $t$:

Right side:

$$\int_{t_0}^{t}1\;dt=t-t_0$$

Left side:

$$\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{x'(t)}{1-x^2(t)}\;dt=\int_{x(t_0)}^{x(t)}\frac{1}{1-y^2}\;dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x(t_0)}^{x(t)}\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{1+y}\;dy=\\=\frac{1}{2}(\ln(x(t)+1)-\ln(1-x(t))-\ln(x(t_0)+1)+\ln(1-x(t_0)))$$

If you put $t_0=0$ and use $x(0)=3$ you get solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$
\frac{x'}{x-1}-\frac{x'}{x+1}=-2,
$$
and hence
$$
\log(x-1)-\log(x+1)=-2t+c,
$$
with $c=-\log 2$, due to the initial condition.
Thus
$$
\frac{x-1}{x+1}=2\mathrm{e}^{-2t},
$$
and hence
$$
x(t)=\frac{1+2\mathrm{e}^{-2t}}{1-2\mathrm{e}^{-2t}}.
$$